# Exporting subset of neo4j database for non-programmer

Tags: export-to-csv

I've been trying to export a subset of my neo4j database based on a query to a csv file.  However, I haven't had much luck.  Most of the advice I've found online requires a significant amount of coding - unfortunately, I have only a cursory knowledge of programming languages and have encountered difficulties trying to get this to work.  Are there any easy methods to do this without requiring a high level understanding of MySQL or Java?  Thanks for your help!